# How to install flycheck in spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs, flycheck

I am attempting to use [`flycheck`](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/) with my spacemacs setup.

The [`spacemacs` documentation](http://spacemacs.org/doc/DOCUMENTATION.html), under "12.4.0.6 Minor Modes" lists `flycheck` as a mode which can be toggled with `SPC t s`.

[image: flycheck spacemacs documentation]

However, no such option is present in my spacemacs setup. Pressing `SPC t` raises a set of options that does not include `s`.

[image: spacemacs no flycheck]

And, if I press `SPC t s` anyway, I get the message `SPC t s is undefined`.

**How can I install flycheck to use with spacemacs?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Flycheck` is provided as part of the `syntax-checking` layer. You need to install that layer in order to use the `Spc t s` keybinding. Check out the layer documentation [here](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bcheckers/syntax-checking). To use it just add `syntax-checking` to your list of `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` like so:

```
(setq-default
 dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
    '(
      syntax-checking
      )
 )
```

Comment: This worked for me. I added `syntax-checking` to the `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` section of my `.spacemacs` file, restarted my emacs -- and presto; compile errors pop up on save.