# Install Flycheck on spacemacs

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, flycheck

Following [this guide](https://github.com/atilaneves/cmake-ide) to configure Spacemacs as a C++ IDE, I am facing an issue when installing [Flycheck](http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/installation.html).

I have followed the instructions explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48142050/how-to-install-flycheck-in-spacemacs) but after adding the `syntax-checking` instruction under `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers`, I have the following error when lauching spacemacs :

```
Error (use-package): flycheck/:init: Symbol’s function definition is void: global-flycheck-mode
```

I am totally new to spacemacs and emacs in general so I might have missed something obvious.

**Emacs version** : 27.0.50

**Spacemacs version** : 0.200.13

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

I add additions package in this function

`dotspacemacs-additional-packages '(org-trello ereader plantuml-mode elmine org-alert org-super-agenda easy-hugo ponylang-mode flycheck-pony flycheck-plantuml)`

and in the `(custom-set-variables` add the packege to  `'(package-selected-packages`

After restart spacemacs, all works for me, hope it will be helpful to you too.